# Android HTC Sensation Screen resolution QHD truncated

Tags: android, screen-resolution

This is driving me nuts!

Using Eclipse to build an app for my HTC Sensation. On the Main.xml tab in Graphical Layout I've created a QHD device config with Portrait and Landscape qualifiers and screen resolution set to 960x540. All looks great in the graphical layout but when I run on my phone the screen is ALWAYS about 1/4 screen too short!

I get the feeling that device config in eclipse on graphical layout is only for eclipse but doesn't do anything on the phone. If so? Where do i set the overall space I want my app to take up on screen.

My project is just a simple linearlayout with width and height set to "Match Parent"

hope you can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: At last. Found it! You MUST target a sufficiently advanced SDK in your manifest or larger screen resolutions are not supported automatically..... Adding the following to your android manifest fixes the problem.

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

Answer (score 1):

I like your comment; it worked for me. since you can't answer your own question, i'll post it for you:

change the `<uses-sdk.../>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to the following:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution for me, but I had to implement it a bit differently...

Using Eclipse I had to set the target SDK in the project properties and the sizing was only correct when using a min SDK version of 4 or higher.